# A single AD user can't log into a single Mac bound to the domain (DirectoryServices error). How can I resolve this?

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, authentication, login

On our campus, we have about 60 Macs joined to our Active Directory domain. Most users have no problems logging into Macs, as long as their accounts are configured correctly.

However, we have one particular user who is unable to log in to just *some* of the Macs. He has no problem with most of them, but there is one group of them (all built from the same image) that he can't log in to. The machine in question is running OS X 10.6.2. The relevant entries from secure.log are below, with the hostname and username redacted.

```
Aug 16 10:32:43 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Could not get the user record for username from DirectoryServices.
Aug 16 10:32:43 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Will sleep 1 seconds and try again (retryCount = 4)
Aug 16 10:32:44 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Could not get the user record for username from DirectoryServices.
Aug 16 10:32:44 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Will sleep 2 seconds and try again (retryCount = 3)
Aug 16 10:32:46 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Could not get the user record for username from DirectoryServices.
Aug 16 10:32:46 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Will sleep 4 seconds and try again (retryCount = 2)
Aug 16 10:33:10 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Could not get the user record for username from DirectoryServices.
Aug 16 10:33:10 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: Will sleep 8 seconds and try again (retryCount = 1)
Aug 16 10:33:18 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: User info context values set for username
Aug 16 10:33:18 hostname SecurityAgent[4411]: unknown-user (username) login attempt PASSED for auditing
```

Everything I've found online suggests that our use of Mobile Accounts is causing the issue. I turned that feature off, but I still can't log in as that user.

`id` returns a record for his account, and nothing looks out of the ordinary.

Has anyone here run into this before?

Comment: upgrade it to a PC ;)

Comment: Can other users log in to those workstations? What if you create a new user on your domain, can you log in with that? Can that user log in to other workstations?

Comment: Luke, I asked this question in August 2010. I don't exactly recall what I did to resolve the issue, but I believe it had something to do with his home directory attribute in Active Directory being an invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected his user record on the AD side of things? I would guess that there's something in his record that DirectoryServices is crapping out on

Comment: His account looks normal. He can log in to every one of our online systems (OWA, etc.) as well as every PC and most of the Macs. The only thing that was different was the primary group, which was set to faculty instead of Domain Users. I've since switched it to Domain Users.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because there was a conflicting local user account by the same name created at some point.  Have you turned off mobile accounts and tried to log in without that feature?  Also, I would unbind and then re-bind any of the problem images from the domain, restart, and then try again.